# MySQL Query Doesn't Return Value, But Exists In DB

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a funky problem.. I have this code:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = this.connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM links WHERE url LIKE '@url'";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", parent_url.Trim());
    cmd.Prepare();

    using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            parent_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }
    }
}
```

What my problem is that.. sometimes it doesn't return a value when there is a an answer in the database. That's very strange. Also I have noticed that some items in the database have a space behind it so this is why I made this:

```
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = this.connection;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM links WHERE url LIKE '@url'";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", parent_url.Trim());
        cmd.Prepare();

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                parent_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
    }

    if(parent_id == 0)
    {
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = this.connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM links WHERE url LIKE '@url '";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", parent_url.Trim());
            cmd.Prepare();

            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    parent_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it still doesn't help me some times.. even if the item doesn't have a space after it.
So yea.. can you guys please give me some advice.. what should I try.

Comment: What kind of column is `url` in the database table?

Answer (score 2):

```
"SELECT id FROM links WHERE url LIKE @url";
```

remove the `''` from the parameter then only it will consider as parameter

otherwise it will be only a string value equal to  `@url`

and also if you need to search given string on database column use `%` like below

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", "%" + parent_url.Trim()+ "%");
```

**UPDATE:**

you can use trim function as below

```
"SELECT id FROM links WHERE trim(url) LIKE @url";
```

Comment: Well, I tried it and it still doesn't find some of the items.

Comment: I can't use % because there will be items similar to to the item I'm looking for. I could use parent_url.Trim() + "%", but it would give me tons of other answers as well.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying RTRIM right now. It will take some time because my database is huge

Comment: Okay well.. this trim(url) method is extremely slow. It should be slow?

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is the quoting around the parameter placeholder. In this way the parsing engine cannot link the placeholder to the parameter.

So your easy fix is

```
"SELECT id FROM links WHERE url LIKE @url";
```

But this is not enough  to resolve the problem of the white space at the end of your url column.

You could fix the extra space problem using this script with MySql Workbench to remove the blank spaces at the end of the URL column once and forever.

```
update links
set url = rtrim(url) 
where url like '% '
```

NOT TESTED, keep a backup at hand please.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, I'll try to change my post's title

Comment: Not tested but the RTRIM function exists also in MySql